# Display each mySQL result as link to another page php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "sbsuite";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from sys_frm WHERE ParamType='Title';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Data"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?
```

This is code that give me two results..

1. Client
2. Server

I want to insert them as link to another php page with image, depends on what we click on its goes to another php page...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you tell in brief what do you want? What is your question?

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting error?

Comment: result that i get from php mysql query display as them to link to another php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple HTML. Replace the `client/server` php and jpg to what you want.

```
<a href="client.php"><img src="client.jpg" alt="Client" /></a><br />
<a href="server.php"><img src="server.jpg" alt="Server" /></a>
```

With PHP

```
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
<a href="<?php echo $row["Data"]; ?>.php"><img src="<?php echo $row["Data"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row["Data"]; ?>" /></a><br />
<?php
}
```